# java makefile "make: Nothing to be done for 'default'"

Tags: java, makefile

I've searched around for answers and alas have come here to ask. What is my best option for getting the make error "make: Nothing to be done for 'default'." for the java project that I am doing.

I've made sure that my indents are correct and I've tried "make clean" and "make default". I am also editing and running this with cygwin on a windows machine, but I am not using anything else but cygwin to create, edit, and run the makefile. I also have the latest java version installed.

Here's my provided makefile

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
      ALU.java \
      Binary_Debugger.java \
      CreateSim.java \
      Data.java \
      IF.java \
      IssueUnit.java \
      MEM.java \
      Pc.java \
      PostALU.java \
      PostMem.java \
      Pre_Issue_Buffer.java \
      PreALU.java \
      PreIssue.java \
      PreMEM.java \
      PrintCycle.java \
      Register.java \
      Write_Back_Unit.java \
      main.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES: .java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

I expect for a .jar file to be compiled, but I just get this error.

Comment: why not compile java in more modern way such as maven or gradle ?

Comment: @howie if it will make a makefile, which is required for me, then I'll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means your classes already exist (therefor nothing is to be done). If you want to rebuild anyway, do a `make clean` first. Like,

```
make clean
make
```

As for jar'ing your compiled classes, you have no `jar` target.

Comment: The jar part from you worked. I have however done a different way of getting the makefile to recognize the classes with the "javac -d . " and "jar cvmf manifest.mf ..." commands.